# How to get full path of the file in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration. I have below code. I have placed a text file in one of the folder in my system and I have configured inbound channel adapter as below:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter channel="filesInChannel"
    directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/input" auto-create-directory="true"  >

    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="1000" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="filesInChannel"> </int:channel>
```

My question is from the channel (`filesInChannel`) how can i come to know the file name including its absolute path?

Ex: my file is located in `C:\someFolder\some.txt`

from channel i should get above path.

Comment: Look at the API for [`InboundChannelAdapter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/archive/1.0.0.M6/apidocs/org/springframework/integration/endpoint/InboundChannelAdapter.html)

Answer (score 3):

What do you want to do, once you have the fileName?

The message payload is a `java.io.File` so you can simply use an expression `payload.absolutePath`, for example:

```
<header-enricher...>
   <header name="foo" expression="payload.absolutePath" />
</header-enricher>
```